# Update plugins through Github?

Tags: git, github

I've got some plugins (JS/AS3) pushed to my Github-account and I'm using them in multiple projects (of-course), which are also processed by Git. If I want to change one of the plugins, can I easily update all these projects with this new version somehow?

I'm not sure about the terminology here (forking? branching? pulling?), so it's kind of tricky to search for this.

Comment: Pulling would be the term you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is submodules in git.

You can check http://progit.org/book/ch6-6.html for a detailed explanation.

Comment: Thanks all! This is a nice explanation as well: http://chrisjean.com/2009/04/20/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/

Answer (score 0):

Use Git submodules on the projects which use your plugins:
http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html